# To push objects to table component in angular

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, angular6

**Scenario:** I have 2 api's called `customers` and `workers`, I am displaying all my `customers` and their `assigned workers` using  **table** in an component called `customers`as in below image:

[image]

When i click on **edit** button of particular **customer**, I am injecting that particular customer object(Ex Customer 1) values to an another component called **edit(dialog component)**,where i am displaying injected `customer` properties`(name,email)` and the `assigned worker properties(name,email,phone)` into the **table**. as in below image:

[image]

As shown in the second image i have placed an another component(workers-list)inside the **edit** component which will show all workers in the dropdown:

[image]

**Expected Result:**

- Now i want **push** those selected workers from `workers-list` component to table present in the `edit` component like this:

[image]

Ex pic: `Worker 2` selected from the `dropdown` and gets added to **table** in `edit` component by clicking `Add` button.

- It should not add duplicates.

> I am receiving `emitted workers` in `edit` component, but i am unable verify **duplicates** and i am unable `push` the **new workers** to `table`.

Since components are many, I am giving **stackblitz [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/loading-object-properties-into-table-by-other-component-twbzzh?file=src/app/edit/edit.component.ts)**.

Comment: You want to push the worker into the edit table or into the main table?

Comment: In want to push into edit table..

Comment: @Shankar Check this if the problem is still there:https://stackblitz.com/edit/loading-object-properties-into-table-by-other-component-ptaqej

Comment: Now i am not facing any duplicate issue, but after deleting an paricular worker object i am facing duplicate issue

Comment: I will give the updated link.. soon,

Comment: I am trying to `delete` and push the new `workers` like this: **https://stackblitz.com/edit/loading-object-properties-into-table-by-other-component-iitjas?file=src%2Fapp%2Fedit%2Fedit.component.html** @PrashantPimpale

Comment: Duplicated are still adding.

Comment: Dont add if the worker is already added that means don't need to delete

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please take a [look](https://stackblitz.com/edit/loading-object-properties-into-table-by-other-component-wvnwbl?file=src/app/edit/edit.component.ts).
To rerender table you need to create a new array like that:

```
this.customerWorkers = [...this.customerWorkers, ...value];
```

To skip empty values (and not add them to table), you can use filter on subject like:

```
this.dataService.onSelectWokers.pipe(
     filter(x => x)
   )
```

Also you need to map workers before pushing them to service, example:

```
const workersMap = this.addForm.value.workerIds;
const workersArray = Object.keys(workersMap).map(x => workersMap[x]);
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: I left with one more requirement,now duplicated are adding how can avoid it.?

Comment: [Like that](https://stackblitz.com/edit/loading-object-properties-into-table-by-other-component-uryyqq?file=src/app/edit/edit.component.ts), using uniqueness filter by id.

Comment: No problem, I'm glad that it helped.